# Heroku Static IP for SFTP

Tags: heroku, amazon-ec2

I have an application deployed to Heroku. I'm using a service that requires me to access their SFTP server using a static ip address. I know Heroku dynos are unreliable in this regard. I have successfully achieved this using the Proximo addon, however, its too expensive for the amount of traffic that I'll be sending (around 500 MB/month). Is there an alternate to this? I'm inclined towards using an EC2 instance but not quite sure what's required to create a proxy or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with an EC2 micro instance; pushing bits around doesn't really consume much CPU, so it's unlikely to get throttled. I would then give that instance an elastic IP address and communicate that address to the other service. (Whatever I choose to do later, I can always spin up another instance and associate it to that IP.) I would then deploy a SOCKS proxy ([Dante](http://www.inet.no/dante/doc/1.3.x/config/server.html)?); SOCKS has pretty widespread application support, and it can handle SFTP just fine.

From here, there are a couple details specific to Heroku -- for one, you'll want to configure your proxy server's EC2 security group such that Heroku can access it (see [Dynos and the Dyno Manifold](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#connecting-to-external-services)). You'll also want to enable authentication on the SOCKS server, since granting Heroku access to your proxy grants *everyone* in Heroku access to your proxy. Then, `heroku config:set SOME_SERVICE_SOCKS_PROXY=socks://user:pass@ip-10-1-2-3.ec2.internal`, and have your application look for that environment variable and do the right thing.

You'll likely be paying $0.01/GB for intra-region data transfer between your proxy and Heroku, since statistically, your application will be in a different availability zone most of the time. Heroku dynos last about 24 hours in production, so while the exact location will dance around unpredictably, it'll probably land in the $0.008/GB range in aggregate. You'll also be paying for the micro instance itself (though [reserved instances](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/reserved-instances/#heavyUtilizationRI) make them stupid cheap) as well as the usual AWS Internet data transfer rates.

Comment: Btw I guess you meant the Private dns with "ip-10-1-2-3.ec2.internal". That didn't work for me. The public did.